# Linq to SQL with REST API?

Tags: sql, linq, api, rest, linq-to-sql

I am wanting to setup a REST API with a legacy database.  I am looking into LINQ to SQL as an option to be the communicator between the database and the REST API.  The order of operations are as follows: client will request data from REST API, REST API receives the "GET" request, calls LINQ to SQL method to get the object requested, object is returned in JSON format to client for client-side processing.  I like LINQ to SQL because it can take a data table and spit out a C# object.

Most of the requests will be "GET"; however, in the future "POST" and "PUT" will be added.

Is this reasonable, or should I look to a different method?  I am a new developer, so please excuse my ignorance!

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373841.aspx

Comment: I may be biased because I run a project, which automatically makes RESTful APIs out of databases. For us this is the best way. You can find a link in my profile or google "database gateway for mobile and web apps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular technologies that you use are just tools that help you achieve a goal.  A means to an end.  That goal is typically to solve some business problem.  It is also good to do so in a robust, flexible and easily extensible way so as to provide the most possible business value in the least amount of time.

If one were to analyze an aspect of your question, using LINQ to SQL is fine.  However, there are any number of ORM solutions that would accomplish a similar result (nHibernate, Entity Framework, ADO.NET).  They all can achieve the goal of solving the business problem.

The important thing to remember is that the specific technology you choose for an implementation is typically not nearly as important as how you go about implementing the solution.  Good and bad code are independent of technology they are written in.

In summary, the technologies that you listed in your question are all excellent technologies that can provide robust, flexible, and easily extensible solutions when used properly.

Comment: If time to market is of value, there is a new middleware called SlashDB (http://slashdb.com), which instantly exposes database content via REST API to authorized web and mobile apps. You get automated API and you can declare arbitrary SQL queries too. Disclaimer: I work there.